# how does ethereum web3js imports "crypto-js"?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

I am a bit confused by the syntax used in the web3.js file of the ethereum repository, although there is no file named crypto-js nor any npm or yarn, how is this import is being done? https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/internal/jsre/deps/web3.js#L1828

Comment: You are looking minified source. I suggest you look original source files.

Comment: this is the built in version that is used inside ethereum console, I want to modify it @MikkoOhtamaa

Comment: is there a way to change the unminified web3 and then inject it  in the ethereum? @MikkoOhtamaa

Comment: You do not need geth Ethereum console. If you want to to run JavaScript, you can just execute web3.js and make it connect whatever Go Ethereum node you are running over HTTP or IPC JSON-RPC.

Comment: Not sure exactly, I do see an npm module [crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) which is being used in ethereum, also [sha3](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/sha3.js). Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javascript file you're looking at (web3.js) is the result of web3's build, i.e., a browserify bundle of the whole web3 project and its dependencies. The entire crypto-js library from npm is bundled in that file - that's why there's no other references to crypto-js within the go-ethereum project. Let's take a look at the object containing the code you've linked, which looks something like this:

```js
{
    //...
    19: [
        function(require, module, exports) {
            //...
            var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
            var sha3 = require('crypto-js/sha3');
            //...
        },
        {
            "crypto-js": 59,
            "crypto-js/sha3": 80
        }
    ]
    //...
}
```

This key/value pair represents a module. The key `19` is an ID for the module within the bundle. The value is an array with two elements: (1) the module code and (2) the module's dependencies. The dependencies are given as an object with module name keys and module ID values. Thus, the `crypto-js` module can be found in the same object under key `59`, and likewise `crypto-js/sha3` under key `80`.

Modifying `web3.js` can be done by obtaining the source and rebuilding it. The version in the `go-ethereum` repo seems to be 0.20.1, which corresponds to commit [996148d3](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/commit/996148d356570745ef20630b499bce37f8484920) in the [web3 repository](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js). Building this version is somewhat of a pain, as back then web3 did not commit `package-lock.json`. I was able to build it by forcing the use of gulp 3.9 and node 10. As for replacing `crypto-js`, you can edit `lib/utils/sha3.js` and replace it with a different `sha3` implementation.

After rebuilding web3, copy `dist/web3-light.js` to `internals/jsre/deps/web3.js` in the `go-ethereum` repo and run `go generate` to regenerate `internals/jsre/deps/bindata.go`. Finally, build `geth`.

Putting this all together:

```sh
# Clone web3
git clone https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js
cd web3.js
git switch -c replace-crypto-js 996148d356570745ef20630b499bce37f8484920

# Edit the sha3 implementation
vim lib/utils/sha3.js

# Build using gulp 3.9 and node 10
sed -i 's/"gulp": ">=3.9.0"/"gulp": "^3.9.0"/' package.json
npm install
npm --no-save install node@10
PATH=./node_modules/.bin gulp

# Clone go-ethereum
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git
cd go-ethereum

# Copy new web3 and regenerate bindata.go
cp ../web3.js/dist/web3-light.js internal/jsre/deps/web3.js
make devtools
PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin go generate internal/jsre/deps/deps.go

# Build geth and test out changes in console
make geth
./build/bin/geth console
```